Finding a general expression for the improper integral $\int_0^\infty K_1( ( k^2+\alpha^2)^{1/2}r)\sin(kz)\,\mathrm{d}k$
$\newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}$
In solving a classical fluid mechanics problem involving flow in porous media, I encountered a delicate infinite integral of the form,
$$
\on{f}\left(r,z; \alpha\right) = \int_{0}^{\infty}
\on{K}_{1}\left(\left[k^{2} + \alpha^{2}\right]^{1/2}\,r\right)
\sin\left(kz\right)\,\mathrm{d}k \, ,
$$
wherein $\alpha$ and $r$ are positive real numbers and $z$ is a real number.

For the specific case where $\alpha = 0$, the integral can be exactly and easily solved as
$$
\on{f}\left(r,z; 0\right) = \frac{\pi}{2}\frac{z}{r}
\left(r^{2} + z^{2}\right)^{-1/2}\, .
$$
I am curious whether a general expression can be derived for the above integral with arbitrary $\alpha$.
By replacing $\on{K}_{1}$ with $\on{K}_{0}$ and the sine function with the cosine function, I managed to obtain the following
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\on{K}_{0}\left(\left[k^{2} + \alpha^{2}\right]^{1/2}\,r\right)
\cos\left(kz\right)\,\mathrm{d}k 
= 
\frac{\pi}{2}
\left(r^{2} + z^{2}\right)^{-1/2}
\exp\left(-\alpha\left[r^{2} + z^{2}\right]^{1/2}\right)
$$
Could anyone provide hints or guidance on how to approach finding a general expression for the original integral ?.

Thank you very much !.

Did you try some CAS like $\tt Maple, Mathematica,\ldots$ ?

@FelixMarin Yes. Both did not know how to solve it unfortunately.

Could you share how you did the $K_0$-version of the integral? Numerically your result checks out, but so far I've only been able to figure out it must be a function of $\sqrt{r^2+z^2}$

Ok, nvm, I found it. For the record, use DLMF (10.32.11)  and this result

@Noctis Awesome
